# PostgreSQL, mixing SUM horizontaly and vertically

Tags: postgresql

I have a temporary table which is result of previously heavy combined data from which I have to create html document to show.

This table in short illustrates situation:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS temp11;
CREATE TABLE temp11 (t_idx int PRIMARY KEY, mydate text, myclass int, mypercent double precision, valpercent double precision, valclass double precision);

INSERT INTO temp11
(t_idx, mydate, myclass, mypercent, valpercent, valclass) VALUES 
(1,  '01.01.2014',  1,  10,      10,      1),
(2,  '01.01.2014',  2,  20,      20,      4),
(3,  '01.01.2014',  2,  20,      50,     10),
(4,  '01.01.2014',  1,  10,      17,    1.7),
(5,  '02.01.2014',  2,  20,      40,      8),
(6,  '02.01.2014',  1,  10,      18,    1.8),
(7,  '02.01.2014',  2,  20,      50,     10),
(8,  '03.01.2014',  1,  10,      10,      1),
(9,  '03.01.2014',  2,  20,      40,      8),
(10, '03.01.2014',  1,  10,      20,      2),
(11, '03.01.2014',  2,  20,      30,      6);
```

Now I have a query for grouping and summing that into dates and valclasses:

```
SELECT mydate, myclass, mypercent, 
      SUM(valpercent)          AS sumvalpercent, 
      SUM(valclass)            AS sumvalclass, 
      SUM(valpercent+valclass) AS sum_row 
FROM  temp11 
GROUP BY mydate, myclass, mypercent 
ORDER BY mydate;
```

Result of this query is expectable:

```
"01.01.2014"   2   20   70  14.0   84.0
"01.01.2014"   1   10   27   2.7   29.7
"02.01.2014"   1   10   18   1.8   19.8
"02.01.2014"   2   20   90  18.0  108.0
"03.01.2014"   2   20   70  14.0   84.0
"03.01.2014"   1   10   30   3.0   33.0
```

But needs are a bit extended.

Is it possible to do with PostgreSQL that in same process after every date I get vertically SUM of data inside that date and after all, at the end, SUM of data from all dates so result will look like this:

```
"01.01.2014"   2   20   70  14.0   84.0
"01.01.2014"   1   10   27   2.7   29.7
                        97  16.7  113.7
"02.01.2014"   1   10   18   1.8   19.8
"02.01.2014"   2   20   90  18.0  108.0
                       108  19.8  127.8
"03.01.2014"   2   20   70  14.0   84.0
"03.01.2014"   1   10   30   3.0   33.0
                       100  17.0  117.0
                       305  53.5  358.5
```

If this is possible such (or similar), how that query should look like with showed data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to use `UNION ALL` to get all the desired output at once.
If you leave out the fact that the dates are shown (needed for the order by clause) this query gives the requested output in the simplest way.

```
SELECT mydate, myclass, mypercent, 
      SUM(valpercent)          AS sumvalpercent, 
      SUM(valclass)            AS sumvalclass, 
      SUM(valpercent+valclass) AS sum_row 
FROM  temp11 
GROUP BY mydate, myclass, mypercent 
UNION ALL
SELECT mydate || ' total', null, null, 
      SUM(valpercent)          AS sumvalpercent, 
      SUM(valclass)            AS sumvalclass, 
      SUM(valpercent+valclass) AS sum_row 
FROM  temp11 
GROUP BY mydate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total', null, null, 
      SUM(valpercent)          AS sumvalpercent, 
      SUM(valclass)            AS sumvalclass, 
      SUM(valpercent+valclass) AS sum_row 
FROM  temp11 
ORDER BY mydate;
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22a33/6)

Perhaps it can be rewritten more elegantly using `WITH`

**EDIT:**

This will be more efficient because it only traverses through `temp11` table just once. Then it only uses the temporary table `temp100` which has much fewer rows for the additional totals (no more than one row per day). The `UNION`s still remain and the logic is still the same.

```
WITH temp100 (mydate,myclass,mypercent, sumvalpercent,sumvalclass,sum_row) as (
  SELECT mydate, myclass, mypercent, 
      SUM(valpercent)          AS sumvalpercent, 
      SUM(valclass)            AS sumvalclass, 
      SUM(valpercent+valclass) AS sum_row 
  FROM  temp11 
  GROUP BY mydate, myclass, mypercent 
)
SELECT mydate,myclass,mypercent, sumvalpercent,sumvalclass,sum_row
FROM temp100
UNION ALL
SELECT mydate || ' total' as mydate, null, null, SUM(sumvalpercent), SUM(sumvalclass), SUM(sum_row)
FROM temp100
GROUP BY mydate
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Total' as mydate, null, null, SUM(sumvalpercent), SUM(sumvalclass), SUM(sum_row)
FROM  temp100
ORDER BY mydate;
```

This is the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/22a33/21)

Comment: Thanks foibs, that gives expectable result and 'flushes' fully ordered outpud in desired order for easily making html report from that. If you can give more elegant solution I would be glad but given one is pretty OK.

Comment: @user973238 I added another alternative which should be faster, especially if you have a lot of data. Cheers

Comment: Here is large data not to be expected but thanks for additional solution. It will be used for educational purposes.